# Do the amount of libraries for Python differ by IDE?

Tags: python, visual-studio, libraries

I switched over to Visual Studio from PyDev and I was wondering whether there would be any difference in the amount of libraries available?

Comment: what kind of libraries are we talking about? Built-in libraries or external libraries (or IDE libraries like debugging tools)? Do you use your systems python with these IDEs or a seperate one?

Comment: No. Libraries for Python are libraries for Python. Why would you think the IDE would make a difference?

Comment: @KenWhite It could be that the python in visual studio is actually IronPython (or not, who knows :) ).

Comment: External libraries,like NumPy

Comment: As long as you set the path to the libraries in the IDE settings, there should be no difference. Better yet, test it out and let us know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IDE makes no difference on the Python libraries that are available to you, the libraries that were available to you on PyDev are still on your machine somewhere.

It's possible this confusion arose because your IDE didn't automatically detect these available libraries, as PyDev might have done, but all you need to do is show it where they are !